# If createJob/createTask works for my function? What is the difference between create multiple jobs and create multiple tasks in one job?

Tags: matlab

I want to run multiple completely independent scripts, which only differs from each other by 1 or 2 parameters, in parallel, so I write the main part as a function and pass the parameters by createJob and createTask as follow:

```
% Run_DMRG_HubbardKondo
UList = [1, 2, 4, 8];
J_UList = [-1, 0:0.2:2];
c = parcluster;
c.NumThreads = 3;
j = createJob(c);
for iU = 1:numel(UList)
    for iJ_U = 1:numel(J_UList)
        t = createTask(j, @DMRG_HubbardKondo, 0, {{UList(iU), J_UList(iJ_U)}});
    end
end
submit(j);
wait(j,'finished')
delete(j);
clear j t
exit
function DMRG_HubbardKondo(U_Job, J_U_Job)
...% (skipped)
end
```

What if I createJob multiple times each with one createTask? I know there are some options like attachedfile in createJob. But with respect to **independency**, is there any difference between createJob and createTask? The reason I ask about independency is that there are setenv inside the DMRG_HubbardKondo function as follow:

```
function DMRG_HubbardKondo(U_Job, J_U_Job)
...% (skipped)
DirTmp = '/tmp/swan';
setenv('LMA', DirTmp)
Para.DateStr = datestr(datetime('now'),30);
% RCDir named by parameter and datetime
Para.RCDir = [DirTmp,'/RCStore',Para.DateStr,sprintf('U%.4gJ%.4g', [U_Job,J_U_Job])];
k = [strfind(Para.Symm,'SU2'), strfind(Para.Symm,'-v')];
if ~isempty(k)
    RC = Para.RCDir
    if exist(RC, 'dir')==0
        mkdir(RC);    % creat if not exist
        fprintf([RC,' made.\n'])
    end
    setenv('RC_STORE', RC);
    setenv('CG_VERBOSE', '0');
end
... % (skipped)
end
```

The main part DMRG_HubbardKondo will use some **mex-compiled functions** which act like **wigner-eckart theorem**. Specifically, it will generate and retrieve data(cg coefficients) in RCDir in every steps. I guess those mex-compiled functions will find the corresponding RCDir by "**getenv**" and I want to know whether createJob/createTask will work correctly.

In summary, my questions are:

1. difference between create multiple tasks in one job and create multiple jobs each with one task.
2. will createJob/createTask work for my function?

I know sbatch will work by writing a script passing parameters to submit.sh as follow:

```
function GenSubmitsh(partition,nodeNo,TLim,NCore,mem,logName,JobName,ParaName,ScriptName)

if isnan(nodeNo)
    nodeStr = '##SBATCH --nodelist=auto \n';
else
    nodeStr = sprintf('#SBATCH --nodelist=node%g \n',nodeNo);
end

Submitsh = sprintf([
    '#!/bin/bash -l \n',...
    '#SBATCH --partition=%s \n',...
    nodeStr,...
    '#SBATCH --exclude=node1051 \n',...
    '#SBATCH --time=%s \n',...
    '#SBATCH --nodes=1 \n',...
    '#SBATCH --ntasks=1 \n',...
    '#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=%g \n',...
    '#SBATCH --mem=%s \n',...
    '#SBATCH --output=%s \n',...
    '#SBATCH --job-name=%s \n',...
    '\n',...
    '##Do not remove or change this line in GU_CLUSTER \n',...
    '##export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK     \n',...
    '\n',...
    'echo "Job Started At" \n',...
    'date \n',...
    '\n',...
    'matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nodisplay -r "ParaName=''%s'',%s" \n',...
    '\n',...
    'echo "Job finished at" \n',...
    'date \n'],...
    partition,TLim,NCore,mem,logName,JobName,ParaName,ScriptName);

fileID = fopen('Submit.sh','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s',Submitsh);
fclose(fileID);

end
```

I hope createJob/createTask will work equivalently.(i.e. completely independent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only minor differences between multiple `createJob` calls each with a single `createTask` vs. single `createJob` with multiple `createTask` calls. I would say it is generally better to use a single Job with multiple Tasks, unless you have a specific reason not to. Here are some considerations:

- Having a single Job object allows some of the stages of the submission process to be done once instead of multiple times (e.g. some pieces of attaching files etc.)
- It is possible (although admittedly awkward) to vectorise the calls to [`createTask`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/createtask.html). (This doesn't affect execution)
- On the [MATLAB Job Scheduler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab-parallel-server/integrate-matlab-job-scheduler.html) (MJS) system, you can set more properties per Job object, such as a range of workers to be used during execution
- When using schedulers such as [SLURM](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab-parallel-server/configure-for-slurm-pbs-pro-lsf-torque.html), multiple Tasks of a single Job can be submitted to the scheduler as a "job array", which I believe can be more efficient for the scheduler itself.
- When using schedulers other than MJS, each Task runs in a fresh MATLAB worker process, regardless of whether it is the only Task in a Job or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But there are some confusions:
1. If I understand correctly, in MJS, each job runs in a fresh MATLAB worker process and the tasks inside one job will be executed by the same worker process, while in other schedulers, each task is equivalent to the job?
2. Regard to the second code block above, there are some "getenv" and "setenv" steps(which guide the mex-compiled functions to load and save the correct data to continue calculations). I'm afraid that the workers can't load correctly since the tasks inside single createJob seem to run in the same MATLAB worker process.

Comment: MJS workers will restart the for the first task in any given job if you set `RestartWorker` to `true`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.job.html . Yes, for most other scheduler types, what they refer to as a "job" is more like what MATLAB refers to as a "task".

Comment: One last question after reading https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html(url): the `parcluster` function will create **Process-based** env, so is single `createJob` with multiple `createTask` calls equivalent to using `system('nohup matlab ...')` one by one? which means that `setenv` within each task will not interference and the I/O process is independent? (I think it is one of the feature that **Process-based** env differs from **Thread-based** env.) If I should create a new post for this question, just let me know.

Comment: It's not quite equivalent. MJS workers can be re-used for multiple tasks. (This is to make things more efficient - no need to wait for the MATLAB process to launch).